# Cocos2d-JSでscheduleを止める方法

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-JS 3.6を使用して

```
this.schedule(this.myTask, 1.0);
```

で呼び出したmyTaskを止めるにはどうすればよいでしょうか?

Cocos2d-XではpauseTargetを使うらしいのですが、うまく呼び出せません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.unschedule(this.myTask);`

でいかがでしょう？

サンプルを作ってみました。

```
window.onload = function(){
cc.game.onStart = function(){

    var currentTimer = 0;
    var timerMax = 5;

    //load resources
    cc.LoaderScene.preload(["HelloWorld.png"], function () {
        var MyScene = cc.Scene.extend({
            onEnter:function () {
                this._super();
                var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
                var sprite = cc.Sprite.create("HelloWorld.png");
                sprite.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
                sprite.setScale(0.8);
                this.addChild(sprite, 0);

                var label = cc.LabelTTF.create("Hello World", "Arial", 40);
                label.setPosition(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
                this.addChild(label, 1);

                //スケジュール登録
                this.schedule(this.myTask, 1.0);
            },
            myTask:function(){
              console.log("ok")
              currentTimer++;
              if(currentTimer == timerMax){

                //スケジュール解除
                this.unschedule(this.myTask);
              }
            }
        });
        cc.director.runScene(new MyScene());
    }, this);
};
cc.game.run("gameCanvas");
```

};